# Advantages of updating through Samsung Kies compared to OTA?

Tags: ota-update, samsung-kies

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and I am still waiting for the KitKat OTA update. If Kies would allow me to end the waiting, I would definitely give it a try.

Does Kies provide any kind of advantage towards getting a pending update?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Kies will inform you of updates faster than OTA will. However, OTA is more convenient because you don't have to plug in your phone to the PC. So, it's really just a matter of getting the updates quicker versus convenience.

Comment: Thanks for responding... Unfortunately, I tried but the update is still not there... On with the waiting!